# how to identify tables created by Drupal while developing LMS

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-modules

I am looking at old LMS application build in drupal using SCORM Integration. It is very difficult to find mapping of drupal generated tables and custom tables.

Is there any way to identify tables created by drupal. `eg. node table`

Comment: get schema from all module contrib , and core , deleted others

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Several module have a definition of structure table stored in a file .install , so you can get database schema of it in hook_install() function . If you're using drush to install module , it will classify all contrib module into contrib folder , you just have to get all install file into contrib module to get schema , and do the same into /modules for the Core.